# Get media of category from wordpress api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Looking for a way to request all media of a certain category (in json format) from the wordpress api.

I've been searching for a way to do this for a few hours now, it seems it used to be possible by using filters but after an update filters are no longer supported.

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/

The official documentation does not seem be describing a way of doing this.

I am using wordpress version 4.8.3.

Does anyone know of a way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this function for add parameter

```
add_filter('rest_media_query', 'my_filters', 10, 2);
function my_filters($args, $request) {
      $you_categorie_name = $request->get_param('media_category');

      if (!empty($you_categorie_name)) {
        $args['media_category'] = $you_categorie_name;
      }
      return $args;
    }
```

URL => wp-json/wp/v2/media?media_category=cat_name

Comment: I feel like this is the right approach bit i can't get it to work, i changed rest_YOURPOSTTYPE_query to rest_media_query and if (!empty($id_sync)) { to if (!empty($you_categorie_name)) { but no luck. Added in in the functions.php of my child theme

Comment: Does not seem to be working, also tried rest_attachment_query and query_vars

Answer (score 0):

```
wp-json/wp/v2/media?filter[media_category]=cat_name
```

Comment: This used to be possible but for some reason they removed this feature in newer versions of wordpress.